# How to make C# Linq Join to get unmatched elements in List

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code sample.

```
var prmsMySql = new List<MySqlParameter>();

var prms = new List<SqlParameter>();

foreach (var objSql in prms)
{
    flag = false;

    foreach (var mySql in prmsMySql)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(objSql.Value) == Convert.ToString(mySql.Value))
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!flag)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I need to find whether the two lists has same values or not i mean in the prmsMySql value 
and prms value (Value field in the Sqlparameter and MySqlparameter).

This code works fine. Is it possible to make linq implemetation to make the code shorter
and readable easily.

I tried the following query.

```
 var flag2 = prms.SelectMany(o => prmsMySql.Where(p => Convert.ToString(o.Value) != 
             Convert.ToString(p.Value)).Distinct());
```

It gives the wrong answer. Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What do you mean by this `if (!flag){flag = false;}` I can't make sense from this.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel hi sorry its by mistaken. I updated the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
prmsMySql.Any(x => prms.Any(p => p.Value.ToString() == x.Value.ToString());
```

Or with `join`

```
(from p1 in prmsMySql
 join p2 in prms 
 on p1.Value.ToString() equals p2.Value.ToString()
 select p1).Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MySqlParameter
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
```

...

```
var lst1 = new List<MySqlParameter> {new MySqlParameter {Value="1"},
                new MySqlParameter {Value="2"},
                new MySqlParameter {Value="3"},
                new MySqlParameter {Value="4"}};

            var lst2 = new List<MySqlParameter> {new MySqlParameter {Value="1"},
                new MySqlParameter {Value="2"},
                new MySqlParameter {Value="3"},
                new MySqlParameter {Value="7"}};

            var res = from l1 in lst1
                      join l2 in lst2 
                      on l1.Value equals l2.Value
                      select new { result = l1 };

            bool flag = res.Count()==lst1.Count();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is LINQ Code for you inner foreach loop

```
 foreach (var objSql in prms)
 {
     flag = prmsMySql.Any(mySql => Convert.ToString(objSql.Value) == Convert.ToString(mySql.Value));

       if (flag) 
           continue;

       break;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you attempting to perform a left outer join?

> ### How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)
>
> A left outer join is a join in which each element of the first collection is returned, regardless of whether it has any correlated
>   elements in the second collection. You can use LINQ to perform a left
>   outer join by calling the DefaultIfEmpty method on the results of a
>   group join.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397895.aspx

```
    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    class Pet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Person Owner { get; set; }
    }

    public static void LeftOuterJoinExample()
    {
        Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
        Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
        Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
        Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

        Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
        Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
        Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
        Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
        Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

        // Create two lists.
        List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
        List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

        var query = from person in people
                    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };

        foreach (var v in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1}", v.FirstName + ":", v.PetName);
        }
    }

    // This code produces the following output: 
    // 
    // Magnus:         Daisy 
    // Terry:          Barley 
    // Terry:          Boots 
    // Terry:          Blue Moon 
    // Charlotte:      Whiskers 
    // Arlene:
```

---

Modify this code to operate upon your classes;

The contents are identical if:

- the `Count` of the result is the same as your `prms` set
- no elements have empty matches.

---

Joins are an imported database tool. Its worth using then to your advantage where possible.